# How to take a particular words from a txt file using powershell

Tags: powershell

One of the my hostraws.txt file shows a data like below,I want the last IP (10.110.20.77) to be exist after trim.

**| df1b0d4d-e240-49b2-aa6f-6ea878f696eb | Test-15-my_i-v2deggvdmd3g     | ACTIVE | 
blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104, 10.110.20.77  |            |**

How can I do that ? Can anyone help me please ?

I want only the IP "10.110.20.77"

I tried three mthords to get the IP.below are the methord which I tried.The **first methord when I tried,along with IP I am getting "|" also**

```
$hosts = Get-Content C:\hostraws.txt

foreach ($line in $hosts)
    {
    $split1 = $line.trim("|")
    $split2 = $split1.Split(",")[1]
    echo $split2 >> C:\ipaddress.txt
    }
```

I am getting output as  **10.110.20.77 |**

How I can get only the IP ?

**2nd methord i tried below**

```
foreach ($line in $hostsraw)
    {
    $split1 = $line.split('|')
echo $split1
    $split2 = $split1.Split('|')[4]
    echo $split2 
    }
```

### Split1 shows below output

```
df1b0d4d-e240-49b2-aa6f-6ea878f696eb
 Test-15-my_i-v2deggvdmd3g
 ACTIVE


 blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104, 10.110.20.77
```

There is a space in split1 output.When I echo $split2 , there is no output at all

**when I used Third methord**, I am getting same IP address multiple times and also getting error in powershell window

```
$hosts = Get-Content C:\hostraws.txt

foreach ($line in $hosts)
    {
    $split1 = $line.Split(',')[1]
    $split2 = $split1.Split(' ')[1]
    $split2 >> C:\ipaddress.txt 
    }
```

### error Below

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:5
+     $split2 = $split1.Split(' ')[1]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:5
+     $split2 = $split1.Split(' ')[1]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:5
+     $split2 = $split1.Split(' ')[1]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:5
+     $split2 = $split1.Split(' ')[1]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:5
+     $split2 = $split1.Split(' ')[1]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

This is how the hostsrwa.txt contents exist.The ipsddress information is not in the same line, its comes in second line.

[hostsrwa.txt screenshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5oO2.jpg)

Comment: did you try substring for example?

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = "| df1b0d4d-e240-49b2-aa6f-6ea878f696eb | Test-15-my_i-v2deggvdmd3g | ACTIVE | blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104, 10.110.20.77 | |"

$partial = $string.Substring($string.IndexOf(",")+2)
$partial.Substring(0, $a.IndexOf(" "))   
#result: 10.110.20.77
```

The first step is assigning the value in the variable `$input`. since powershell autocast the datatype we can call methods for string like [Substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx) or [IndexOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx).

**when this solution will not work:** (strings were concatenated)

when there will be more or equal 1 occurrence of "," from the start to the original one

```
",,,,,, | ACTIVE | blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104, 10.110.20.77 | |" #fail
"| ACTIVE | blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104, 10.110.20.77 ,,,| |" #ok
```

different position of the desired IP from the first occurrence of `,`

```
"| ACTIVE | blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104,         10.110.20.77 | |" #fail
```

if the space will not be right after the IP

```
"| ACTIVE | blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104, 10.110.20.77|      |" #fail
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but you can use the example in the included image to parse your line of text. It works like this: split at the pipe character, return the line on index 4 (zero based), split at the space character, and return index 2. The last line in the image isn't necessary. Its only purpose was to indicate it's only returning the IP and not any extra spaces on either side of the IP address.

[image]

Edit: If you can do it once, you can always put it in a loop. Consider that my stackfile.txt file has four entries. Using the looping example in the below image will get each IP address.

[image]

As suggested, here's the code from the images. The last two in this first section lost their square brackets around the numeric 2.

```
'| df1b0d4d-e240-49b2-aa6f-6ea878f696eb | Test-15-my_i-v2deggvdmd3g | ACTIVE | blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104, 10.110.20.77 | |'.Split('|')

'| df1b0d4d-e240-49b2-aa6f-6ea878f696eb | Test-15-my_i-v2deggvdmd3g | ACTIVE | blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104, 10.110.20.77 | |'.Split('|')[4]

'| df1b0d4d-e240-49b2-aa6f-6ea878f696eb | Test-15-my_i-v2deggvdmd3g | ACTIVE | blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104, 10.110.20.77 | |'.Split('|')[4].Split(' ')

'| df1b0d4d-e240-49b2-aa6f-6ea878f696eb | Test-15-my_i-v2deggvdmd3g | ACTIVE | blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104, 10.110.20.77 | |'.Split('|')[4].Split(' ')[2]

'| df1b0d4d-e240-49b2-aa6f-6ea878f696eb | Test-15-my_i-v2deggvdmd3g | ACTIVE | blcos10a-private=10.106.15.104, 10.110.20.77 | |'.Split('|')[4].Split(' ')[2].Length
```

and

```
$FileContent = Get-Content -Path .\Desktop\stackfile.txt
Foreach ($Line in $FileContent) {
    $Line.Split('|')[4].Split(' ')[2]
}
```

Note: the .\Desktop\stackfile.txt included four lines where the IP was 10.111.20.77, 10.112.20.78, 10.113.20.79, and 10.114.20.80

Comment: is it possible to add these in for loop condition ? Actually the lengthy output I am getting in a hostsraw.txt file and after trim I have to write the IP to another test file named ipaddress.txt

Comment: I've edited my above post with some information that you'll likely find helpful.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Thanks Tommy. The script is not working.It may be due to the format difference in hostraw.txt .I am also getting errors too. I have edited and attached the hostraw.txt file .Please have a look and suggest

Comment: finally I got it                                                                                                 foreach ($line in $hostsraw)
{
$split1 = $line.split("|")[0].split(",")[1]

echo $split1 >> C:\ipaddress.txt 
}

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is firstly, see where you want the first split, there seems to only by one instance of a `,` where you need that IP address, so...

```
$split1 = $line.Split(',')[1]
```

This will create a capture of `10.110.20.77 | |` and store it in `$split1`

Now you can split it by whitespace and select the first instance again like so:

```
$split2 = $split1.Split(' ')[1]
```

This will create a capture of `10.110.20.77` and store it in `$split2`

```
$hosts = Get-Content C:\hostraws.txt

ForEach ($line in $hosts)
    {
    #split by comma and take first instance
    $split1 = $line.Split(',')[1]

    #split by whitespace and take first instance
    $split2 = $split1.Split(' ')[1]

    #Append to file
    $split2 >> C:\ipaddress.txt
    }
```

I have tested the above and kept it similar to your coding style. This will produce exactly how you require, as long as every line in your hostraws.txt is in that same format.

Comment: Thanks Will. The script is not working.It may be due to the format difference in hostraw.txt .I am also getting errors too. I have edited and attached the hostraw.txt file and errors above.Please have a look and suggest

Comment: that's your issue right there, your txt file is 2 lines for each one, where as your original post indicated that the line was on its own line.